# Ordering in Typo3 Neos template

Tags: neoscms, typoscript2

I created a site template for a website in Typo3 Neos. However, in the template I need to define the  ordering of the javascript because the CSS files have to be included before the javascript files. I now have these files:

Default.html:

```html
{namespace neos=TYPO3\Neos\ViewHelpers}
{namespace ts=TYPO3\TypoScript\ViewHelpers}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <f:section name="meta">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
    </f:section>

    <f:section name="stylesheets">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="{f:uri.resource(path: 'css/bootstrap.css', package: 'MyApp')}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{f:uri.resource(path: 'css/responsive.css', package: 'MyApp')}" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Plugins -->
        <link href="{f:uri.resource(path: 'plugins/flexslider/flexslider.css', package: 'MyApp')}" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Theme style -->
        <link href="{f:uri.resource(path: 'css/theme-style.css', package: 'MyApp')}" rel="stylesheet">
    </f:section>

    <f:section name="headScripts">
        <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="{f:uri.resource(path: 'js/html5.js', package: 'MyApp')}"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!--Retina.js plugin - @see: http://retinajs.com/-->
        <script src="{f:uri.resource(path: 'plugins/retina/retina.js', package: 'MyApp')}"></script> 
    </f:section>
</head>
```

And the Root.ts2:

```
page = Page {
head {

    meta = TYPO3.TypoScript:Template {
        templatePath = 'resource://MyApp/Private/Templates/Page/Default.html'
        sectionName = 'meta'
        title = ${q(node).property('title')}
    }

    stylesheets.site = TYPO3.TypoScript:Template {
        templatePath = 'resource://MyApp/Private/Templates/Page/Default.html'
        sectionName = 'stylesheets'
    }

    javascripts.site = TYPO3.TypoScript:Template {
        templatePath = 'resource://MyApp/Private/Templates/Page/Default.html'
        sectionName = 'headScripts'
    }
}

body {
    templatePath = 'resource://MyApp/Private/Templates/Page/Default.html'
    sectionName = 'body'
    parts {
        menu = Menu
        breadcrumb = Breadcrumb
    }
    // These are your content areas, you can define as many as you want, just name them and the nodePath.
    content {
        // The default content section
        main = PrimaryContent {
            nodePath = 'main'
        }
    }

    javascripts.site = TYPO3.TypoScript:Template {
        templatePath = 'resource://MyApp/Private/Templates/Page/Default.html'
        sectionName = 'bodyScripts'
    }
}
}
```

The result in the HTML is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><!--
 This website is powered by TYPO3 Neos, the next generation CMS, a free Open
 Source Enterprise Content Management System licensed under the GNU/GPL.

 TYPO3 Neos is based on Flow, a powerful PHP application framework licensed under the GNU/LGPL.

 More information and contribution opportunities at http://neos.typo3.org and http://flow.typo3.org
--><head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Home</title>
    
        <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://app.local/_Resources/Static/Packages/MyApp/js/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!--Retina.js plugin - @see: http://retinajs.com/-->
        <script src="http://app.local/_Resources/Static/Packages/MyApp/plugins/retina/retina.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="http://app.local/_Resources/Static/Packages/MyApp/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://app.local/_Resources/Static/Packages/MyApp/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Plugins -->
        <link href="http://app.local/_Resources/Static/Packages/MyApp/plugins/flexslider/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Theme style -->
        <link href="http://app.local/_Resources/Static/Packages/MyApp/css/theme-style.css" rel="stylesheet">

 

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
    

    </head><body>
```

However I want the meta information at the top, then the stylesheets and finally the javascript files to be included. Is it possible to define the ordering of the elements rendered? I would expect the ordering of the Default.html would be used, but it appears not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is @position in typo script, which you can use to alter ordering.. To see in action, check `TYPO3.Neos/Resources/Private/TypoScript/Prototypes/Page.ts2`. In your case it should work:

```
meta.@position = 'start 5'
stylesheets.@position = 'start 10'
javascripts.@position = 'start 15'
```

or you can put it directly into definition:

```
meta = TYPO3.TypoScript:Template {
    @position = 'start 5'
```

You can also use sth like `'after headTag'` or `'before stylesheets'`.

Regarding TypoScript - [TypoScript 2 Pocket Reference](http://learn-neos.com/_Resources/Persistent/dbdcfe4949f0b33b952f8cc645ba12f8a2041764/LearnNeos-TS2-PocketReference-v1.1-int.pdf) is worth checking :)